# backend - шаблоны андроид приложений или как правильно строить приложения

Tags: java, android

Есть 23 классических шаблона проектирования, но уровень их абстракции довольно высокий и никакого готового кода они предоставляют. Андроид разработка существуют давно и наверняка есть более приближенные абстракции (к этому можно отнести и examples  от Gogle). 
 Какие  подсказки и направления вы дали бы себе прошлому, который изучив андроид SDK и пройдя всякие курсы по разработке, стоял бы перед вопросом "как правильно строить приложения"?    Например источники с подобными материалами:  объясняют когда лучше использовать `asyncTask` для запроса по сети, а когда `service`. 
 Появились конструкторы андроид приложений, например конструктор для постройки приложения для ТАКСИ. Увидев этот код можно было бы сделать много полезных выводов. Такой код конечно бесплатно никто не даст, даже интерфейс таких конструкторов платный. Но хоть что нибудь близкое к этому. Я считаю лучше увидеть как приложение подобного типа сделано и повторить его и понять все детали, чем долго писать его самому нарываясь на все грабли. Да во втором случае знаний и понимая больше, но коэффициент выхлоп/затраченное время  будет ниже. Многие, конечно не согласятся, но я не имею ввиду грубое шаблонное проектирование.

Comment: Жаль, вот этого не было раньше :) https://developer.android.com/jetpack/

Comment: да, полезно, но маловато )

Comment: на github множество исходных кодов всевозможных программ и библиотек. Google публикует приложение-эталон для изучеения исходного кода с последними трендами - [iosched](https://github.com/google/iosched) в разработке (организация интерфейса, архитектура, паттерны, типовые приемы и тд)